# TypeError in my __unicode__ method on a Django Model

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models

I bit confuse with `__unicode__()` in django. I'm still a newbie.

I have this code:

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="OR Number")
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="OR Date")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.order_num
```

I register it on the admin side. When I tried to add order it has an error:

```
TypeError at /admin/store/order/add/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found
```

What will I declare on the method `__unicode__(self)`?

It is clear I don't have string on my fields. How can I declare buffer?

or

Anyone has another answer.. please help.. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__unicode__` needs to return a `unicode` object.

The error you see is because only string or buffer-protocol objects can be automatically converted (it's still better to explicitly convert them).

For built-in Python types, or any user-defined class that has its own `__unicode__` method, you can just call `unicode` on them:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.order_num)
```

Comment: I know. there is a 15 minute buffer time before you can accept answers. I'm just waiting for the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `__unicode__` function like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.order_num
```

More info in [Other model instance methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode)

Comment: Since you're not actually doing any formatting, you don't really need to use string formatting.